# ignore pen (stylus) inputs

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

Is there a was to not recognize pen inputs with hammer.js?

I can ignore pen by checking the event type but i want them not to be recognized in the first place.

My goal is to hold the pen on the screen and simultaneously pan or pinch per touch. The problem in here is that even if I ignore the input it won't allow/hinders further pan or pinch gestures.